# Mecha anime with female villain put into cryo-sleep

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I'm trying to identify an anime I saw on TV 15-20 years ago. It was a mecha anime (maybe one of the Gundams?) with two space empires at war. The "bad" side was led by a female commander, and at the end of the series she and her fleet were defeated. Instead of being killed, she chose to be put into eternal cryo-sleep as her punishment.

I was a kid when I watched this, so the details could be wrong in various places; sorry in advance. I vaguely remember the female commander had green hair, but this might be wrong too.

Comment: See if Vandread looks familiar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandread

Comment: @jo1storm I've watched *Vandread* a long time ago and AFAIR the description is far from being similar.

Comment: @jo1storm thanks for the response! Unfortunately Vandread doesn't seem to be the one. I just watched the last episode and both the story and atmosphere seem different from what I remember. The one I was looking for was much darker...